# How do I make Guild Wars download all its content at once?

Tags: guild-wars

I've just reinstalled Guild Wars, without the CDs. I'm using directly the client installer from their site. It downloaded and installed some files for a while, and then it launched. However now, each zone I go to has to download before, if I go there for the first time.

Is there a way to make Guild Wars preload all of its content, instead of retrieving it "on demand"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. What you have to do is create a new shortcut with the switch `-image`.

So copy your shortcut to Guild Wars (don't use your normal shortcut), right-click on it, choose Properties and in the target box add `-image` so that it looks like
`“C:\Program Files\Guild Wars\gw.exe” -image`

Mind you that this is a lengthy process, it might even take a couple of hours.

Comment: Yes, but I have time in front of me to download, so that's why I prefer to preload everything before. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: Just warning you and anyone else who might stumble on the question. ;-)